# Cantor countability of a set that always could be written in a row with two look alike ends

Tags: elementary-set-theory

There is unavoidable pressure to clear the question because I lose reputation and would be blocked to ask any questions here. Such is life.

New form of the question: The set is a "chain" set. It has first and last elements always. This means you can think about that set as a row with two ends (of the chain) (see title). The set almost look counted! One can enumerate it from left to right, but because set has last element, there is always the question what index got the last one. Cantor insist that it must be finite index, simply naturals haven't any other indexes. It can be tried the proof by contradiction. Let suppose that the set is sequenced then clearly sequence has last element. The set can be rearranged anyhow (to please Noah) but this not break the chain structure of the set it still forming one chain albeit with different order. Again, last element escape the sequence. Conclusion is such that because N+1 is countable, chain-set must be uncountable. But I put additional axiom to these of Peano, defining last element by analogy of first element. Clearly such set exists and in form of a chain and can be infinite exactly N+1. The question is where I go wrong?

Old face of the same question.
The set under question resembled the finite set but is infinite. It starts with a < b < c ..... and ends with x < y < z, always. The last word means two things. Firstly, the set is completely ordered in a row, and second, writing the set as a row is always possible and as such, give order to the set. Then, such a set is almost like the set of natural numbers, for example there is equivalent of the mathematical induction for that row. The difference is that this set-row ending looks like the beginning of the natural order of natural set i.e. there is last element as well as first element, always.

The question is: Is it that set countable by Cantor?

I must confess that that one is crystallized form of what I asked in my previous questions [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1863383/about-cantors-proof-of-uncountability-of-real-numbers).
Oh, the board message system warns me that you can block me from asking any more questions, because of bad reputation of mine. The choice is kindly yours.

Edit PostScript
This set is natural set with last element. Lets try counting this set-row, first we pick the most left, then the most right element and this finish the counting. But lets look differently. For every n starting with 1, the set-row always have last element left in the row being counted so it is true for all naturals N. 
Equivalent legitimate question is: What index would get the last element of the row?
The term "last element" is elusive it is morphing element, because every time you get to submerge last element, someone else take the role of the last one. So, basically we always have last element which happen to left uncounted. Remember N+1.

In other words, let suppose contrary that we have counting sequence. By definition of this set this sequence is a row with last element. Question, under which index it stays in sequence?

Is it the missing real in the Cantor sequence of all reals? Possible.
This question is connected with infinite permutations. Is it such permutation can be constructed only with swap of the two elements without knowing the exact places of these elements? Just one swaps two hands. If yes, then clearly there are bijections and bijections.

Comment: What do you mean by "in a row"? If you can write it in a row such that every element is listed, then clearly it is finite.

Comment: Or do you mean by "in a row" that every element except the smallest has a predecessor and every element except the largest has a successor?

Comment: Do you mean that every pair of things has one sometime after the other? Or do you mean that every thing except the first and the last has a "next" thing and a "previous" thing?

Comment: Or do you mean a totally ordered set such that every nonempty subset of it has both a first and a last element?

Comment: @McFry When you look under magnifying glass of the beginning you see a,b,c. When you look and the end you see x,y,z. When look at the "middle" you see .,.,., dots representing elements. I wouldn't bet that such a set that looks a chain is finite. yes to three first comments. It is more like naturals with one more element, the biggest "natural" number.

Comment: @Henning Makholm It is exactly as naturals but has ending, which can be reverse counted. I mean one more axiom to Peano three, that the set N has last (biggest) element. The end of Infinity looks like beginning. Than the proposed set is strangely uncountable, I am wondering.

Comment: @FeedBack Okay, you know what, how about you just give an example of an infinite set that works like you describe it.

Comment: @McFry It's a thinkable set, with morphing elements the elements just kept   its count but nothing more. No one of the Cantor's bag tricks works. There is always one escaping element. Let suppose this set is countable. Sequenced. Rowwed. Ups. Than clearly that row has last element by definition of the set. Then which index gets that last element? Exactly that real number that escape countability of reals.

Comment: @FeedBack "It's a thinkable set, with morphing elements" Unfortunately, no such set exists. **Just because something is imaginable, doesn't mean it exists.** If you want, try to prove the existence of such a set . . .

Comment: @MarkS. Yes. Think of naturals with added last element. Something as chain, but this chain can't be rearranged. It doesn't make sense, because of this Cantor's tricks doesn't work. Infinite permutations are well defined as for finite set, always. Because of this, the proof for uncountability of reals tell me that my set is uncountable even I know that it is just with one more elements than naturals. Funny. I must write a paper about that :)

Comment: @FeedBack You can't just declare that the elements of a set can't be rearranged - that's not how sets work . . .

Comment: @NoahSchweber You don't pick me literally. It means that rearranging doesn't give you advantage in counting about such row-set. The real intuitive counting is that you just start to exhaust natural numbers for indexes i.e. doing enumeration. I seek cardinality which fine grained plus one element. You see doing bijection exhaust the sets. So you can left untied first horse to second tree and so on so you left with vacant tree for which you can tie a extra horse. You can't hide {∞} in first n naturals because there is always extra element taking role of last element in that set.Where I am wrong?

Answer (score 3):

It's not very clear what kind of set you are describing, but here are two reasonable interpretations:

- The set $S$ looks like a copy of $\mathbb{N}$, followed by a "backwards" copy of $\mathbb{N}$. For example, maybe $$S=\{-{1\over n}: n\in\mathbb{N}\}\cup\{{1\over n}: n\in\mathbb{N}\}.$$ In this case, $S$ is indeed countable. Keep in mind that countability is about *cardinality*, and cardinality lets us rearrange terms without respecting order: so this $S$ is countable because it can be rearranged to look like two copies of $\mathbb{N}$, and the union of two countable sets is again countable.
- $S$ is allowed to be much more general: it begins with something that looks like $\mathbb{N}$, ends with something that looks like backwards-$\mathbb{N}$, but might have other stuff in the middle. In this case, $S$ might be uncountable: for instance, maybe $$S=\{-{1\over n}: n\in\mathbb{N}\}\cup[0, 1]\cup \{1+{1\over n}: n\in\mathbb{N}\}.$$

Comment: O'key the question need a joker. I think about that set as natural set plus one more element. I put it because naturals haven't biggest element.  But that isn't obligate to. You can start count it from the left, from the right and use tricks of Cantor about integers or rationals or why not reals, I mean diagonal counting. If you can't put bijection between such a set and naturals, that not means that the set is uncountable, just you as me not  succeeded to demonstrate (un)countability of the set. I mean that the set can be started of counting, but always one element escape the process.

Comment: @FeedBack To the extent to which your comment makes sense, the answer is yes, it is countable. It doesn't matter if one ordering of the set makes it look like the naturals + some stuff; the question is whether there is *some* ordering which makes it look like the naturals. (This is why, e.g., the rationals are countable.)

Comment: Think again. Look my vague questions before. You have sequence, you know that the set is countable by heart (joker) but in fact that set has "always" last element which escape counting. Remember the popular Cantor proof for reals in decimal writing. You can prove by contradiction that set can't be N+1, because of that. But that no convince me.

Comment: @FeedBack If you can clarify your question - maybe give an example of such a set, or write more precisely what you mean - then I can respond usefully. But at present there's really nothing I can say, because I don't really understand what you're asking. And just saying "that no convince me" isn't really an argument against countability . . . (Also, what do you mean by "you know that the set is countable . . . but in fact that set has "always" last element which escape counting"? These two statements, to the extent to which I understand them, contradict each other. (cont'd)

Comment: A set is countable if and only if there is some listing of it - that is, injection into $\mathbb{N}$. If a set is countable, it **can't** always have an element which escapes counting -  that's what "countable" **means**!)

Comment: I use for this set axioms of Peano plus one additional I put last natural element. Than clearly new set is chained, any replacement of its elements just rearranging the chain and because of that additional element I claim that the set is uncountable but is really with no more elements than naturals + one.  Funny.

Comment: @FeedBack Unfortunately, your claim is wrong. The set you describe is in bijection with the naturals (bijections need *not* preserve order), so it is countable.

Comment: @(Noah Schweber) Think again. Let suppose you have your bijection, than you have sequence of the set. Please, can you tell me what index got  the last element of the written row?

Comment: @FeedBack For instance, the set $\mathbb{N}\cup\{\infty\}$ can be put into bijection with $\mathbb{N}$ by sending $\infty$ (the last element) to $1$ and $x$ to $x+1$ for $x\in\mathbb{N}$. Of course, we could also send $\infty$ to (say) $17$. The point is just that there **exists** such a bijection - it doesn't have to respect order, or be unique, or anything else.

Comment: And if what you want is a set which is countable but whenever you try to count it, you wind up with (at least) one element left over - well, that's a contradiction in terms. Just because you can imagine something, doesn't mean it exists. Indeed, this is how Cantor's diagonal argument works: any listing of elements of $\mathbb{R}$ leaves out at least one element, so $\mathbb{R}$ is not countable.

Comment: @(Noah Schweber) I know Cantor. I respect Cantor. But his proof telling me that my thinkable set can't be N+1. So someone tell me that the bug can't fly regards its mass but I really thought (can being thinking) of this set as N+1. Why not? This thinkable set has just its cardinality. No tricks of counting. Real counting a flock of sheep. Counting starts and counting ends.

Comment: @FeedBack Um, too bad, I guess? I can also imagine there being natural numbers satisfying $a^n+b^n=c^n$ with $n>2$ - it doesn't mean that such things exist. If you want to actually do math, as opposed to just talk about it, you need to be willing to be skeptical about the objects you imagine - do they actually exist? how do you know? The kind of object you describe simply does not exist (at least, not in anything resembling ZFC set theory).

Comment: @(NoahSchweber) You haven't problem that number one hasn't preceding number, so my set has one more axiom that contain similar but last element. Why such a set impossible. Is it a Riemann set?